# How do I sort descending in dataweave?

Tags: dataweave

This works for ascending.

`vars.results orderBy (results) -> results.name`

but can't figure out how to sort descending by name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(vars.results orderBy (results) -> results.name)[-1 to 0]
```